# Running Odoo 10 on command line

Tags: python, odoo

Hi I'm new to Odoo and I'm trying to run the server using this command on windows shell: `odoo-bin --addons-path addons,my-modules` as the documentation says
But I am getting this error:

```
odoo-bin: error: option --addons-path: no such directory: 'addons'
```

I have this to path adding to my variable enivrement:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo-bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your variable environment, addons folder is supposed to be located with the same level of odoo-bin.

My guess is that you have the structure below.

```
server
|----- addons
|----- debian
|----- doc
|----- odoo
|----- setup
|----- odoo-bin
.....
```

If above is right try replacing your path inclusion with below.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server
```

Side Note:
You should use a config file to make it easier for you to manage configurations

Comment: I have this : C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo\addons and this: C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 10.0\server\odoo-bin
 What do I do ?

Comment: remove them, and try what I suggested